# Trying to create a Map[String, String] from lines in a text file, keep getting errors

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

Hi so I'm trying to create a Map[String, String] based on a text file, in the textfile there are arbritrary lines that begin with ";;;" that I ignore with the function and the lines that i dont ignore are the key-> values. they are separated by 2 spaces.

whenever i run my code i get an error saying the expected type Map[String,String] isn't the required type, even though my conversions seem correct.

```
def createMap(filename: String): Map[String,String] = {
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
      if (line.nonEmpty && !line.startsWith(";;;")) {
        val string: String = line.toString
        val splits: Array[String] = string.split("  ")
        splits.map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1)).toMap
      }
    }
  }
```

I expect it to return a (String -> String) map but instead i get a bunch of errors. how would i fix this?

Comment: You are declaring a function that should return a `Map[String, String]`  but your implementation only returns `Unit` _(Additionally you are not creating any map)_. **Scala** does not really has a `for` in the sense of **Java** or **C++**, it is just _syntactic sugar_ for either a call to the `foreach` method, that returns `Unit` _(which is what you made here)_. Or for nested calls of `map`, `flatMap` & `filter` _(which you could use to return your actual Map)_. See [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) & [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

Comment: oh alright, so how would i change it so it actually returns a map?

Comment: You only need to use the proper syntax _(using `yield`)_, I am sure that if you read both links, you will make it work ;) BTW, I remember you from yesterday. I just noticed that my previous answer has an error in that what _splits_ your key for your value are **two** spaces _(instead of one)_ and that for that reason your splitted array will always had two elements. I will update my previous answer with the fix in a moment. If that keeps you giving trouble ask there or here _(if you believe that ameritates another answer)_.

Comment: yup i remember ur comment it was extremely helpful but for some reason it did not return every single value in the textfile, some were missing. for reference, here is the text flie http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b, if you want to test it yourself to see if its the same with you to make sure its not just me.

some words are completely missing/incomplete which is why i tried doing the above to see if i could come up with my own solution using what u recommended to no avail

Comment: also remove D�J�  D EY2 JH AA1 when u download the text file its a corrupt string

Comment: at this moment I can not test it by myself _(sorry for that)_, but are you sure there are missing values?, that may happen if two keys are the same. Maybe the splitting does not work as intended in every line. As jvwh said, you may try desugaring the `for` and add debugging steps, to check everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since your if statement is not an expression in the for-loop. You should use the if as a filter when yielding your results. To return a result, you must make it a for-comprehension. After the for-comprehension filters the results. You can map this structure to a Map.

```
import scala.io.Source
def createMap(filename: String): Map[String,String] = {
  val keyValuePairs = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines; if line.nonEmpty && !line.startsWith(";;;")) yield {
      val string = line.toString
      val splits: Array[String] = string.split("  ")
      splits(0) -> splits(1)
  }
  keyValuePairs.toMap
}
```

---

Okay, so I took a second look. It looks like the file has some corrupt encodings. You can try this as a solution. It worked in my Scala REPL:

```
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
import scala.io.{Codec, Source}

def createMap(filename: String): Map[String,String] = {
  val decoder = Codec.UTF8.decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)
  Source.fromFile(filename)(decoder).getLines()
    .filter(line => line.nonEmpty && !line.startsWith(";;;"))
    .flatMap(line => {
      val arr = line.split("\\s+")
      arr match {
        case Array(key, value) => Some(key -> value)
        case Array(key, values@_*) => Some(key -> values.mkString(" "))
        case _ => None
      }
    }).toMap
}
```

Comment: thanks, this sort of worked as well, still getting an issue with missing values

Comment: By missing values, do you mean that the map is populating empty strings??
Maybe split on whitespace if that's the case
`val string = line.split("\\s+")`

Comment: impartial keys, completely missing keys, here's the textfile im parsing http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b

Comment: What keys will be missing? Can you give an example of some results expected in the Map[String, String]?

Comment: so i just ran the function again to find you some examples, the map starts off like this

(CKI(1) -> R IH2 B AA1 K IY0)

the "CKI(1) is impartial, the entire word is (RYBACKI(1)  R IH2 B AA1 K IY0) as it says in the textfile i showed you. something is going wrong somewhere and idk why or what

Comment: there are also hundreds of other words missing, ive been at this for a few hours now and still cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: When I ran this I have a map of size 133,855, which appears to be the line count for lines that don't have ;;; in the beginning. I'm not sure if this is what you want to do with the values, but you can manipulate the split in each case

Comment: so it seems u were right there is a corrupt text in the file! i just had to delete it and now the function works perfectly, thanks a ton this was a learning experience for sure.

Comment: @user11039395 glad it helped and you learned a lot